# Does an Angular 2 '@Component' decorator always need an element name selector?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, angular-components

In this example, from the official Angular 2 docs, the decorator looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular App</h1>'
})
```

**Example:** would prefer not not have my HTML code littered with non-standard elements, and **would prefer** something like (NB: `ng-angular` is only an example I would like to see):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  template: '<h1>Wait! Bloody wait some more.</h1>'
})
export class ListComponent { }
```

and used something like this:

```
<div ng-component="List"</div>
```

Or is the a Component decorator like this used only when you want to create a new HTML element, and then stick to a plain `Listcontroller` for the `div` in my example above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A selector is not always needed eg. you have a top component of a module that is loaded by router and displayed in

selector is needed for any other type of component. otherwise angular wouldn't know what component it should render.

I haven't heard about attribute "ng-component"

**[EDIT]**
*kit effectively answered correctly in his/her first comment:*

You have to create an element that would enclose your template however it doesn't have to be a new HTML element because selector can be a element, [attribute] or class, eg.

```
<div test>
```

could be an element for component with selector: '[test]'

Comment: I don't want to know if a component needs a selector or not. I re-iterate that I want to know if creating a new component always results in a new HTML element, or is there some way to link a component to a standard element like a `div`. I said I would "prefer to see something like" an `ng-component` attribute. That is purely an example..

Comment: You have to create an element that would enclose your template however it doesn't have to be a new HTML element because selector can be a element, [attribute] or class, eg. <div test> could be an element for component with selector: '[test]'

Comment: Oh! Wonderful, thank you. I am still in the overviews examples stage, and have not seen one, out of a great many, Continent with anything but an element selector. You deserve more points for this than I can give you now. Please be patient.

Answer (score 1):

A component is a new HTML element, something like `<my-component>Hello</my-component>`.

I think what you want is a [directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html).

> An Attribute directive changes the appearance or behavior of a DOM element.

So you can do something like `<div makeItBlue>Blue stuff</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate: The selector can be a standard CSS-selector, so your HTML can be non-angular-centric.

Example:

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'div.player-list',
        ...
    })
    export class PlayerList {
    }
```

will match `<div class="player-list and-possibly-some-other-classes">...</div>` (i.e. replacing the div with your angular template)